# Null Pointer Exception when testing wsdl2Apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, webservices, wsdl2apex

I am trying to write a simple apex test class for the wsdl2apex file that i generated, but for some reason I am getting a null pointer exception in the test method which mocks the apex callout. I developed this with reference to the documentation at - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm The problem is in below class at line `respElement.orderResponse.CorrelationID = '23145';` where orderResponse is an inner class.  Here is my apex test classes:

```
@isTest
global class GcsmsWebmethodsMock implements WebServiceMock{

global void doInvoke(Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType){

  gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.processOrderResponse respElement = new gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.processOrderResponse();
  respElement.orderResponse.CorrelationID = '23145';
  response.put('response_x', respElement);


}

}
```

Class which calls webservice:

```
public class WebSvcCallout {
    public static gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderResponse callEchoString(String input) {
    gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.MU650_GCSMS_Order_v1_webservices_order_wsd_pro_Port sample = new gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.MU650_GCSMS_Order_v1_webservices_order_wsd_pro_Port();
        sample.endpoint_x = 'http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar';

        gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderInput req = new gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderInput();
        // This invokes the EchoString method in the generated class
        gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderResponse res = sample.processOrder(req);

        return res;
    }   
}
```

The test class which calls the web service. here I get null pointer exception - attempted to de-reference null object(please see the comment below at which line)

```
@isTest
private class WebSvcCalloutTest {
    @isTest static void testEchoString() {              
        // This causes a fake response to be generated
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new GcsmsWebmethodsMock());

        // Call the method that invokes a callout
        gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderResponse output = WebSvcCallout.callEchoString('Hello World!'); // null pointer exception - //attempted to de-reference null object

        // Verify that a fake result is returned
        System.assertEquals('23145', output.CorrelationID); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the communities time here. I have found the bug on my own. I did not initialize the object in my test class before using it. So the resolution should be to create an object of class orderResponse and use this object to assign a value to correlationID.

```
  gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.processOrderResponse respElement = new gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.processOrderResponse();
  gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderResponse obj2 = new gcsmsWebmethodsNaJnjComMu650Gcsms.orderResponse();
  obj2.CorrelationID = '23145';
 respElement.orderResponse = obj2;
```

Above change to the first class solves the problem.